# Laravel Validation : Match one of two values

Tags: laravel

I have a title attribute in my list of field to validate, instead of checking if it's a string, how can I check that it's equal either to `M` or `MME`?

```
$attributes = [
  'title' => ['string']
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->user, $attributes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'in' validation rule.

```
'title' => ['in:M,MME'],
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-in